# Determining a country by GPS coordinates

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager

I have some GPS coordinates powered by LocationManager. When device connects to internet I must check in which country I have been. Are there any services that allows you to send an GPS location and receive a country in response?

Comment: I don't believe you spent at least a minute searching, while you have to.

Comment: Hiking or just "normal travel"? In the last cases, the Geocoder (like in the answer is correct. In the first case Geocoder is not precise.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko I really believe he / she did - for query "determine what country gps location belongs to", this question is a first result in Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get all the details that are stored as address in the given Longitude and Latitude.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
List<String>  providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
if(null!=locations && null!=providerList && providerList.size()>0){                 
double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());                 
try {
    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
        String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

If you need more details for the Longitude and Latitude, You can you this,

```
public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                + obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the permissions in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Geocoder you can get country like this:

```
private String getCountry(double latitude, double longitude) {
        try {
            List<Address> addresses;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); 
            return addresses.get(0).getCountryName();;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  "Unknown address";
    }
```